# Select element in unequal nested list and plot

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two list of data

```
vdata = {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.};

sol = {{-96.29,-0.07,-0.00,0.95}, {-32.29,-0.06,-0.00},{-32.29,-0.03,-0.03,0.95},{-32.29,0.95},{-32.29,42.80}, {-32.29, 0.95}};
```

The `sol` is the corresponding solutions for `vdata` , so for a given element in `vdata` there can be `2 or 3 or 4` (Eg. size of the nested list is different) solutions.

I want to select only the solutions that lie in the range `0<=sol<=1`, and plot it with the corresponding `vdata` (also note that for `vdata=0.8` `sol={-32.29,42.80}` so this does not satisfy the constraints so should not be included in the plot).

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Try `Select[Between[{0, 1}]] /@ sol`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Its working :-). How to select the corresponding `vdata` simultaneously ? As for `vdata=0.8` its giving empty list.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. For removing the empty list I found a command `Select[list, UnsameQ[#, {}] &]` , but how about to find the corresponding `vdata`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {vdata, sol //. {x_ /; ((x > 1) || (x < 0)) -> Nothing}}]
```

However, note that the conditions you give do not always result in a single choice.

```
{{0., {0., 0.95}}, {0.2, {0.}}, {0.4, {0.95}}, {0.6, {0.95}}, {0.8, {}}, {1., {0.95}}}
```

Which do you actually want to select?

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
Thread /@ DeleteCases[DeleteCases[MapThread[List, {vdata, sol}], x_?NumericQ /; 0 <= x <= 1 // Except, {3}], {_, {}}]
ListPlot[%, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02]]
```

> {{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.95}}, {{0.2, 0.}}, {{0.4, 0.95}}, {{0.6, 
>      0.95}}, {{1., 0.95}}}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Catenate[MapThread[Thread@*List, {vdata, Pick[sol, sol - Clip[sol, {0, 1}], 0.]}]]
```

> {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.95}, {0.2, 0.}, {0.4, 0.95}, {0.6, 0.95}, {1., 0.95}}

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
vs = (Thread /@ Transpose[{vdata, Select[0 <= # <= 1 & ] /@ sol}]) /. {} -> {Missing[]};
ListPlot[vs, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, 
 GridLines -> {None, vdata}, PlotLegends -> (ToString /@ vdata)]
```

[image]